# Modify dictionary in csv file using user input and save

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I cannot find a straight solution to my problem (maybe a very simple one, but still...) neither here, nor on the internet.

I have created a dictionary and saved it in a CSV file using `csv.DictWriter`

```
# Starting dict
d= {'key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2'}

# Writing down the dict and saving
with open('mycsvDict.csv', 'w') as f:
    w= csv.DictWriter(f, d.keys())
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerow(d)
```

Now that I have my dictionary in a CSV file, I am reading it back into a dictionary and trying to modify it with user input.

```
# Ask user for new key, value
data_to_append= {}
user_key= input("Write new key: ")
user_val= float(input("Insert new value: "))

data_to_append[user_key]= user_val

#trying to append in the file
with open('mycsvDict.csv', 'a') as app_f:
    from csv import writer
    w= csv.DictWriter(app_f, data_to_append.keys())
    w.writerow(data_to_append)

print(data_to_append)
```

I get the new dict with the new key and value from the user printed correctly (ofc), but my CSV file is not being modified.
I can't save the new updated version.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there any error that pops up?

Comment: No, no errors. But the code doesn't perform what I would like to do.
It doesn't append the new item (with value) in the original file.

Comment: I tried it and it worked. Is this an accurate representation of your code? Please also post expected output.

Comment: That said, I don't think this is what you're looking for. The dictionary writer prints the keys as headers and values as rows. If you are getting the user input for the keys, regardless of what the keys are, the row will be written in the order of the dictionary that is defined. This means that it wouldn't be matching the key with the original columns. Is that really how you want to populate your CSV file?

Comment: Oh, that's nice. I mean, I wrote here to get new knowledge also.
So, what steps do you recommend me?  I wish that the new key,value would had been added to the dictionary

Comment: You can try the suggested answer by writing the key and the value on the same line. It really depends on what kind of output you want to get. Say for the super simple example you gave, how should the CSV file look like if `user_key` is `'key1'` and if it is `'key3'`. That is, the scenario when the key matches an existing field and when it doesn't.

Comment: Ok, I'll working on it. Sorry for the simple example but I am at the beginning of my "python journey" and I am experimenting! Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work as per your expectation

```
with open('mycsvDict.csv', 'a') as app_f:
    for key in data_to_append.keys():
        app_f.write("%s,%s\n" % (key, data_to_append[key]))
```

Comment: @Marco do you want to add the key value pair to the next line or to the next column? My code adds it to the next line. I think that's not what you are looking for

Comment: I opened the file csv as excel after trying your code and I prefer as you code does, so having the new items (key and value) on the next line. At this moment I have created a dict that has keys in one line and values in the next line, but it seems simpler to visualise if the pair key,value is on the same line.

Comment: Yeah It will be easier to load it in dictionary and you can verify before appending whether the key already exists or not

Comment: Instead of iterating on keys, it might be better to iterate directly on the key-value tuple though.

Comment: With time, I ll want to check whether a key exist already and also I 'd like to work (maybe with some calculations) inside values of a specific key.